# CSS not working in AJAX Load

Tags: css, ajax, load

Basically, I have an AJAX load function that loads content from a content.html file into a content div.

Every page of my site takes the information from the same content.html file.

The CSS classes are linked to this content.html file via it's own content.css file.

Website: www.crookedcartoon.co.uk

For my first page (Print.html), all the content that gets loaded into it from the content.html file and has all the CSS intact, and works perfectly.

When i get to my second page (Design.html), the css doesn't work.

When opening the content.html file locally, the css is completely fine on everything, it just stops working once the AJAX loads it into the div but only on that second page.

Can anyone help? This is driving me mad, i can't seem to find why it's not working, i've even tried moving all the content for this second page onto a new content2.html file and loading it from that, but still the problems sticks.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't spot the problem in Design.html

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're seeing or having problems with. However, here's what I noticed:

1. This is actually only a problem on the "Salt Town" subpage. All the rest look fine.
2. You have `class='content-header2'` and `class='content-text2'` on the relevant "Salt Town" divs. The rest of them use `content-header` and `content-text`. If you change that, it works fine.

Note: DID work fine. When I went back to double check, the links were broken. I assume you're tinkering with it, and that's part of the reason it's customary to include a link to an example with the problem on jsfiddle, jsbin, or another similar site.

Comment: The main problem is the date, it simply won't accept a p class, apologies for tinkering, i tried creating a brand new p class (simply putting 2 after it) but that didn't help.

Comment: The a class for the link "Salt Town" also doesnt work, same goes for all the left nav loaded content on the design page. The print sub pages are all fine, and they have the exact same coding.

Comment: Upon looking at the developer tools, it doesnt seem to be recognising any css linked to that specific paragraph, and i cant see why, simply says element style {

Comment: There is no `content-header` class defined in the CSS.

Comment: You really need to edit your question to be more specific about your problems. Saying it "Doesn't work" doesn't give enough information to anyone trying to help.

Comment: I see I mean, all the content being loaded into that div is from the same hmtl file (That goes for all the subpages on the print page), and that html file is being loaded via AJAX .load into the content div (print.html) content2 div (design.html)

The class content-header is being utilised on all the print.html subpages but not on any of the design.html subpages, even though all these subpages are form the same content.html file (being loaded via ajax) with the same .css file linked to said content.html file.

I don't quite understand why it isn't recognising the content-header class.

Comment: I don't know how to be more clear. There is no `content-header` class defined in the `design.css` CSS file included in the design page.

Comment: Apologies, i was expecting the content to take it's css from the stylesheet linked to the content.html file, clearly once it's loaded via ajax, it takes all it's style from the page it gets loaded into, and it's linked css files.